# JBoss Forge Generated REST Endpoint Returns NULL Entity

Tags: java, rest, jboss7.x, jboss-arquillian

I am using JBoss Forge to generate a REST API for my application. The endpoint has been generated for an entity named Message with the following command (package name is obfuscated):

```
rest endpoint-from-entity x.x.x.Message --contentType application/xml
```

This results in a MessageEndpoint.java with the following create method:

> ```
> @Stateless
> @Path("/messages")
> public class MessageEndpoint
> {
>    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "forge-default")
>    private EntityManager em;
>
>    @POST
>    @Consumes("application/xml")
>    public Response create(Message entity)
>    {
>       em.persist(entity);
>       return Response.created(UriBuilder.fromResource(MessageEndpoint.class).path(String.valueOf(entity.getId())).build()).build();
>    }
> ```
>
> ......

To create a test for the endpoint, I used the following command:

```
arquillian create-test --class x.x.x.MessageEndpoint.java --enableJPA
```

I then extended the default test in the generated test class, MessageEndpointTest.java, to show that getEntity() on the Response object returns null:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class MessageEndpointTest
{
   @Inject
   private MessageEndpoint messageEndpoint;

   @Deployment
   public static JavaArchive createDeployment()
   {
      return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class, "test.jar")
            .addClass(MessageEndpoint.class)
            .addClass(Message.class)
            .addAsManifestResource("META-INF/persistence.xml", "persistence.xml")
            .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
   }

   @Test
   public void testIsDeployed()
   {
      Assert.assertNotNull(messageEndpoint);
      Response r = messageEndpoint.create(new Message());
      Assert.assertNotNull(r.getEntity()); // getEntity returns null
   }
}
```

The new Message is received by the application server and persisted in the database.

When debugging the server, I can see that the entity does get an ID, which is given as 
argument to the method creating the `Response`.

There are no errors in the application server log.

I am using JBoss EAP 6.1 and JBoss Forge version 1.3.3 in Eclipse Kepler.

Can anyone spot what is going wrong or give some advice for debugging?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so after checking [RFC-2614 (Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1)](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.2), I can see I was not expecting the right response from a REST creation. RFC-2613 states that:

> The newly created resource can be referenced by the URI(s) returned in
>   the entity of the response, with the most specific URI for the
>   resource given by a Location header field

Updating my test code according to this new found wisdom thus looks like the following:

```
   @Test
   public void testIsDeployed()
   {
      Assert.assertNotNull(damnedendpoint);
      Response r = damnedendpoint.create(new Damned());
      URI location = (URI)r.getMetadata().get("Location").get(0); // URI = "/messages/<id of the newly created Message>" 
      Assert.assertNotNull(location);
   }
```